# Opening url with æøå, using URL.openStream (Java)

Tags: java, url

I am trying get some xml from the openweatherapi, but I have a problem when the url contains æ, ø or å.

What fails is:

```
URL website = new URL(params[0]);
InputStream inputStream = website.openStream(); // here it throws an FileNotFoundException
InputSource input = new InputSource(inputStream);
```

The params[0] could be: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=århus,&mode=xml&units=metric

The entire code is:

```
public class GetWeatherInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String weatherInfo = null;

        try {
            URL website = new URL(params[0]);
            InputStream inputStream = website.openStream();
            InputSource input = new InputSource(inputStream);

            SAXParserFactory saxp = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = saxp.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xmlReader = sp.getXMLReader();

            HandlingXMLStuff handler = new HandlingXMLStuff();
            xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);               

            xmlReader.parse(input);             

            weatherInfo = handler.info.dataToString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return weatherInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like you need to URL-encode the URL string first? If you enter the URL as you provide it in Chrome, you get a response, but I guess Chrome does the URL encoding itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the special characters. Construct a URI object and then use the `toASCIIString()` method to escape the special characters. This can be done as follows

```
    try {
        String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=århus,&mode=xml&units=metric";
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        URL escapedUrl = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // handle exception
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       // handle exception
    }
```

Now, this means, that in your example, you can do the following:

```
URL website = new URL(new URI(params[0]).toASCIIString());
```